# trying to add a button that will delete intire db row. why isn't my code working?

Tags: php, angularjs

im trying to add a delete button to my "customers" table to delete each row with angular and php but the code isn't working. can anyone help? i can retrieve all information, now trying to delete.

config.php

```
<?php

/****** Database Details *********/

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "hamatkin";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db($database,$con);

/*******************************/

?>
```

deleteCustomer.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
   mysql_select_db('ngdb');
   $id = $_GET ['id'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
   $records = mysql_query($sql);

   if(isset($_GET ['customer_id'])){
       $id = $_GET ['customer_id'];
       $delete = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id= '$id'";
       $res = mysql_query($delete) or die ("FAILED" .mysql_error());
?>
   }
```

controller:

```
"use strict";

angular.module('dataSystem').controller('customerCardsCtrl', function($scope,$route,$location,$http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/get-allCustomers.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.customers = arr;
      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.

      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });

      $scope.delete = function(deletingId, index){

          $http.get("api/deleteCustomer?customer_id=" + deletingId)
              .success(function(data){
                  $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
              })
      }


});
```

html code:

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >

</head>
<body>
    <h2>כרטיסי לקוחות</h2>
    <!-- <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCardDetails">לחץ לפרטי כרטיס לקוח</a> -->

    <div class="search">
       <label>חיפוש:</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="search_query">
       <label>מיון לפי:</label>
       <select ng-model="order_query">
           <option value="kind_Of_Customer" >סוג לקוח</option>
           <option value="first_name">שם</option>
           <option value="id">ת"ז</option>
       </select>
       <label>מיון הפוך:</label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="reverse_query" value="reverse" >
   </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table  class="customer-list table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- <th>#</th> -->
            <th class="Column-Header">מספר לקוח</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">סוג לקוח</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">שם פרטי</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">שם משפחה</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">ת.ז</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">עיר</th>
            <!-- <th>כתובת</th> -->
            <!-- <th>מס' טלפון</th> -->
            <!-- <th>מס' טלפון 2</th> -->
            <!-- <th>אימייל</th> -->
            <!-- <th>פקס</th> -->
            <!-- <th>הופנה דרך</th> -->
            <!-- <th>הערות</th> -->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in customers | filter:search_query | orderBy: order_query:reverse_query">
            <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.last_name }}</td>
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
            <td><input type="button" ng-click="delete(row.customer_id, $index)">Delete<td>
            <!-- <td> {{ x.address}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.phone}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.phone_2}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.email}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.fax}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.referrer}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.comments}} </td> -->
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really switch to pdo (mysql is deprecated).

Comment: More than that, your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.  Don't be like Bobby Tables. http://bobby-tables.com/